# The footer does not see the flexbox, so it is at the top of the images. How do I get the footer down to the bottom of the webpage responsively?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, footer

The footer does not "see" the flexbox nor the images. So, it is at the top of the page. How do I get the footer down to the bottom of the webpage (below the images) and responsively?

```css
footer {
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px black;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 10px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.column {
  flex: 20%;
  max-width: 20%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.column img {
  margin-top: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="/gallery/jediandjulie.webp"><br>
    <div class="name">Jedi (right)</div><br>
    <img src="/gallery/abc_xylophone.webp">
    <div class="name">abc_xylophone</div><br>
    <img src="/gallery/blueice.webp">
    <div class="name">blueice</div><br>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="/gallery/fern1.webp"><br>
    <div class="name">Fern</div><br>
    <img src="/gallery/cgeezy-612x1024.webp">
    <div class="name">cgeezy</div><br>
    <img src="/gallery/charlie_m.jpg">
    <div class="name">charlie_m</div><br>
    <img src="/gallery/cnc3.webp">
    <div class="name">cnc</div><br>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="/gallery/foosh4.webp"><br>
    <div class="name">foosh</div><br>
    <img src="/gallery/epl2.webp">
    <div class="name">epl692</div><br>
    <img src="/gallery/Erika.jpeg">
    <div class="name">erika</div><br>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="/gallery/zeused13-225x300.jpg"><br>
    <div class="name">zeused13</div><br>
    <img src="/gallery/funkmanshades.webp">
    <div class="name">funkman</div><br>
    <img src="/gallery/gabby.webp">
    <div class="name">Gabby</div><br>
  </div>
</div>

<footer class="center">
  <hr class="style-two">
  <p>Copyright &copy; TheVillage.care</p>
</footer>
```

Fixed with this:

I made a parent element to stretch down to the bottom where the footer was placed under.

```
<div class"parent">...everything...</div>
<footer>...</footer>
.parent {margin-bottom:3000px}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give margin-bottom: 300px to class row, and with footer { position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; } position footer so that it is always on bottom of page. Or you can even give padding-bottom: 300px to body(or parent component) to do the same thing. Don't forget to give body(or parent component) { position: relative }

Comment: Good idea. I made a parent element to stretch down to the bottom where the footer was placed under. <div class"parent">...</div> <footer>...</footer> .parent {margin-bottom:3000px}

Answer (score 0):

You can use margin, and padding, to distance the footer to the bottom
Ex: margin-top:30px....
Or
Better solution use postion:fixed.